# Best way to detect if a path exists between two nodes a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

The description of the question is the following.

A program would read a file by lines to build up a graph. Each line in the file would be one of theses three kinds of operations:

1. `add x y`, which means adding an edge between node x and y,so that a graph would be formed. This graph is a undirected graph.
2. `remove x y`, which means removing an edge between node x and y, if it's not valid(x or y does not appear to exist in graph or not edges exists between x and y), then do nothing.
3. `is linked x y`, which should return if x and y can be connected through all the edges in the graph. The time complexity of this operation should be constant time.

Here is an example:

```
   add 1 2  
   add 2 3
   is linked 1 3(should be true ,cause there is a path 1-> 2, 2->3)
   add 3 4
   remove 2 3
   is linked 1 4(should be false)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Edit your post to clarify it.

Comment: Look for connected component ? Do you have the specifications of the connected component to search for ? Or do you just want to see if the graph has 'n' number of connected components ? Do you want this in constant time ? I don't think so.

Comment: Do you have any time constraints on the add and remove operations? Otherwise you could just build a Boolean connectivity matrix each time you update the graph. Checking for connectivity is then possible in constant time with the cost of add and remove going up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73504595/4393351

Answer (score 1):

You can use union-find data structure to do that in [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) time of near linear. For its structure and implementation details you can google the **union by rank with path compression**. You can find many academic notes about that with pictorial tutorials and precise time/space-complexity analysis. This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) and this [one](https://www.slideshare.net/WeiLi73/time-complexity-of-union-find-55858534) can help.

*But two notes here:*

Its complexity is amortized. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333376/difference-between-average-case-and-amortized-analysis) if you want to compare it with worst-case analysis.

What means near linear? The amortized analysis of the algorithm is equal to inverse Ackermann  function noted by α ( n ).

> where α ( n ) {\displaystyle \alpha (n)} \alpha (n) is the inverse Ackermann function. This function has a value α ( n ) < 5 {\displaystyle \alpha (n)<5} {\displaystyle \alpha (n)<5} for any value of n that can be written in this physical universe, so the disjoint-set operations take place in essentially constant time