# DFS | BFS : Check if path exists between node A and node B

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

In a bidirectional graph check if a path exists between node A and node B.

My code does not work for certain input (samples provided below). Is this implementation correct or I missed something?

```
bool[] visited = null;
public bool ValidPath(int n, int[][] edges, int start, int end) {
    IList<int>[] adjacencyList = new List<int>[n];
    visited = new bool[n];
    
    // create adjacency list
    for(int i = 0; i < edges.Length; i++){
        int a = edges[i][0];
        int b = edges[i][1];
        
        if(adjacencyList[a] == null)
            adjacencyList[a] = new List<int>();
        adjacencyList[a].Add(b);
        
        if(adjacencyList[b] == null)
            adjacencyList[b] = new List<int>();
        adjacencyList[b].Add(a);            
    }
    
    return DFS(adjacencyList, start, end);
}

private bool DFS(IList<int>[] adjacencyList, int start, int end){
    if(start == end) return true;
    
    if(!visited[start]){
        visited[start] = true;
        foreach(var v in adjacencyList[start]){
            if(v == end) return true;
            if(!visited[v])
                DFS(adjacencyList, v, end);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works for below examples:

Input: n = 3, edges = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]], start = 0, end = 2
Output: true

Input: n = 6, edges = [[0,1],[0,2],[3,5],[5,4],[4,3]], start = 0, end = 5
Output: false

Does not work for below (expected return value is true but I get false):

Input: 10, edges = [[4,3],[1,4],[4,8],[1,7],[6,4],[4,2],[7,4],[4,0],[0,9],[5,4]], start = 5, end = 9

Comment: 1. why is the question tagged with BFS ? 2. consider adding comments and using meaningful names instead of a,b,n to make the code more readable.

Comment: @c0der 1. Removed BFS tag 2. It is conceptually explain the requirement. Examples and code samples related to that

Comment: `if(!visited[v] && DFS(adjacencyList, v, end)) return true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is correct, with the only issue being that inside the recursive `DFS`, you need to keep track of the result of all the subsequent `DFS` calls. If any of the recursive calls return true, then the solution should return true (instead of directly returning false). Here is the slightly modified version of the `DFS` function that works :

```
private bool DFS(IList<int>[] adjacencyList, int start, int end){
  if(start == end) return true;

  bool status = false;
  if(!visited[start]){
    visited[start] = true;
    foreach(var v in adjacencyList[start]){
        if(v == end) {
            return true;
        }
        if(!visited[v]) {
            status = status || DFS(adjacencyList, v, end);
        }
    }
  }
  return status;
}
```

**Update :**
Thanks to the suggestion in the comments. If `DFS` for any of the adjacent vertices returns true, then the method can directly return true (instead of making `DFS` call for other adjacent vertices and keeping that `status`). That gives us another variation of `DFS` :

```
private bool DFS(IList<int>[] adjacencyList, int start, int end){
  if (start == end) return true;

  bool status = false;
  if(!visited[start]){
    visited[start] = true;
    foreach(var v in adjacencyList[start]){
        if(v == end) {
            return true;
        }
        if(!visited[v] && DFS(adjacencyList, v, end)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
  }
  return status;
}
```

Comment: You can return immediately if you return `true` from `DFS` instead of continuing to search for more paths. I would do something like `if (DFS(...)) return true;` instead of updating this `status` variable.

Comment: Agreed! That could be another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it will pass all the testcases. It is based on `BFS`.

```
            //int[][] edges = new int[][]
            //{
            //    new int[] { 0, 1 },
            //    new int[] { 1, 2 },
            //    new int[] { 2, 0 }
            //};
public static bool ValidPath(int[][] edges, int source, int destination)
        {


            if (source == destination) return true;

            var graph = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < edges.Length; i++)
            {
                var pair = edges[i];

                if (!graph.ContainsKey(pair[0])) graph.Add(pair[0], new List<int>());
                if (!graph.ContainsKey(pair[1])) graph.Add(pair[1], new List<int>());

                graph[pair[0]].Add(pair[1]);
                graph[pair[1]].Add(pair[0]);
            }

            var visited = new HashSet<int>();
            visited.Add(source);

            var queue = new Queue<int>();
            queue.Enqueue(source);

            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                var vertex = queue.Dequeue();
                if (vertex == destination) return true;
                foreach (var next in graph[vertex])
                {
                    if (visited.Contains(next)) continue;
                    visited.Add(next);
                    queue.Enqueue(next);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```